# Topology counter example

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

-We known that every subspace of T2 space is T2space..
but If we reverse it
-if A is subspace of X and A was a T2 space need to be space X T2space also.?
If the statement is wrong plz given example.

Comment: Any nonempty space $X$ has a normal Hausdorff subspace consisting of a single point.

Comment: @Tyrone What do I conclude from this statements plz explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a single point $\{x\}$ in any space $X$ is Hausdorff, regardless of what separation axioms $X$ satisfies.

For a more sophisticated example you can take any Hausdorff space $A$ and add a point to it $X:=A\sqcup\{*\}$ with the following topology: $U\subseteq X$ is open if and only if $U=X$ or $U\subseteq A$ is open. Forget about Hausdorfness, the special $\{*\}$ is not even closed in $X$. But $A\subseteq X$ is Hausdorff.

The statement isn't even true if we assume that $X$ has all proper subsets Hausdorff, as the trivial topology on $\{1,2\}$ shows.